# how to add 48 hours to a timestamp

Tags: php, date, date-math

I am using this code to minus 48 hours from a timestamp

```
echo date($result2["datetime"], strtotime("-48 hours"));
```

This works fine, i want to add 48 hours, i have tried:

```
echo date($result2["datetime"], strtotime("+48 hours"));
```

I have echoed `$result2["datetime"];` which shows a timestamp in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

and when i use:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+48 hours"));
```

that adds the 48 hours on fine too

When i use

```
echo date($result2["datetime"], strtotime("+48 hours"));
```

Its just echoing the same timestamp thats returned from `$result2["datetime"];` and not +48 hours

Comment: looks like it coming from a db, so could be dome in mysql also. formatting and subtraction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first parameter for `date()` is the format you want the date output in. The second parameter is the value you wish to format. There you will use `strtotime()` to add your 48 hours.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($result2["datetime"] . " +48 hours"));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/208482)

or:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+48 hours", strtotime($result2["datetime"])));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/208490)

This is kind of ugly, though. I recommend using `DateTime()` instead:

```
echo (new DateTime($result2["datetime"]))->modify('+48 hours')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/208483)